# R collapse and auto fill blanks in rows

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I have the following example dataset:

```
ID = c(123,123)
NAmer = c("ABC","ABC")
field1 =  c(1,NA)
field2 =  c(NA,2)
field3 = c(NA,NA)
field4 = c(NA,NA)
field5 = c(NA,NA)
IHave <- data.frame(ID,NAmer,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5)
Iwant <- c(123,"ABC",1,2,NA,NA,NA)
```

How do I go from `IHave` to `Iwant` using `data.table` or `tidyverse`?

In practice I have some 000 rows.

Comment: Thank you all, I accepted @akrun 's answer, but I could have gone for either really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the example, after grouping by 'ID', 'NAmer', keep only the non-NA elements if there is atleast one non-NA element

```
library(dplyr)
IHave %>% 
   group_by(ID, NAmer) %>%
   summarise_all(list(~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA else .[!is.na(.)]))
# A tibble: 1 x 7
# Groups:   ID [1]
#    ID NAmer field1 field2 field3 field4 field5
#  <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl> 
#1   123 ABC        1      2 NA     NA     NA
```

---

Or using group by `coalesce`

```
IHave %>%
    group_by(ID, NAmer) %>% 
    summarise_all(list(~ coalesce(!!! .))) 
# A tibble: 1 x 7
# Groups:   ID [1]
#    ID NAmer field1 field2 field3 field4 field5
#  <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl> 
#1   123 ABC        1      2 NA     NA     NA
```

---

Or the same logic in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(IHave)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) coalesce(!!! x)), .(ID, NAmer)]
#    ID NAmer field1 field2 field3 field4 field5
#1: 123   ABC      1      2     NA     NA     NA
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `map` over the columns, `reduce` ing each of them with the `coalesce` function. The function `map_dfc` is used instead of `map` so that it c-binds them together as a data frame (df). So the first column is `reduce(IHave[[1]], coalesce)`, etc.

```
library(tidyverse)

map_dfc(IHave, reduce, coalesce)
# # A tibble: 1 x 7
#      ID NAmer field1 field2 field3 field4 field5
#   <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl> 
# 1   123 ABC        1      2 NA     NA     NA
```

If you want to do this separately for each `ID, NAmer` group, you can use the code below instead.

```
IHave %>% 
  group_by(ID, NAmer) %>% 
  summarise_all(reduce, coalesce)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could transpose your data and use `coalesce` from `dplyr`

```
do.call(dplyr::coalesce, as.data.frame(t(IHave), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
# [1] "123" "ABC" " 1"  " 2"  NA    NA    NA
```

The result is a character vector.